# Android Checkbox button image doesn't wrap content properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Hi I'm currently doing a layout for my project and I need a checkbox for the play button which changes into a pause button on click so I use a selector for that part which is this one

pause_play_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/pause" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/play"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/play"/>
</selector>
```

and here is my Checkbox xml

```
<CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/play_pauseBtn"
            android:button="@drawable/pause_play_selector" android:checked="false"/>
```

on viewing in designer part it displays just fine having all the image for the checkbox displayed but after I install it into my device only half of it shows.

Here's the screenshot:

On layout editor

[image]

On my device see the trimmed down play button:

[image]

Does anyone here expirienced this? Any solution for this problem?

Comment: Do you set any paddings or margins? It will help you with UI debugging to set different background colors on all the views on your screen, so you can see what's overlapping what and each view's actual bounds.

Comment: i think you make res->drawable folder and put all images.can i right?

Comment: I never set any margins or paddings currently. I will try the background color now. :)

Comment: @Harshid, yes I created a drawable folder but it's purpose is only so that I can manage all the xml which controls my drawables. But all of my images are stored in different folders for different resolutions.

Comment: Ok now it's working after I added a background image with the same icon as the play button but is there's any other way around for this to work without adding a background image? since I didn't want it to appear like that.

Comment: This doesn't seem like normal behavior... are you using 9-patch drawables for the buttons?

Comment: @npace yes it's 9 patch. Well I think it's because since I didn't set the background image for this one which is why only the checkbox button part has a background. after I set a background image for this everything works like charm.